# Клиент для для PostgreSQL не видит хост localhost, запущенный в docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

Хочу выполнить тестовое задание для одного дела, и для этого надо использовать контейнер в Docker и связаться с ним через клиент для PostgreSQL (и то, и другое делаю впервые). Образ скачивается, запускается, внутри контейнера должен запуститься сервер PostgreSQL.
[image: вид Docker с открытием и запуском образа]

Однако клиент для PostgreSQL (сперва sQuirell SQL Client, теперь SQL Manager for PostgreSQL) не может подключиться к базе данных. Настройки для подключения есть (host, port, dbname, username, password) - всё ввожу, но выпадает ошибка:
[image: ошибка SQL Manager for PostgreSQL]

Может, я не вижу чего-то простого? Я всё это впервые пытаюсь сделать. Прошу помочь.

Comment: "внутри контейнера должен запуститься сервер PostgreSQL.". Может приведете Ваш Dockerfile?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что вы от меня хотите, то вот инструкции, которым я следую:
Теперь вы можетете скачать наш образ:

docker pull yzh44yzh/wg_forge_backend_env:1.1

И запустить его:

docker run -p 5432:5432 -d yzh44yzh/wg_forge_backend_env:1.1

Comment: Запустил контейнер в соответствии с README и подцепился клиентом, вроде всё ок. `docker run -p 5432:5432 -d yzh44yzh/wg_forge_backend_env:1.1` `psql --host=localhost --user=postgres wg_forge_db` Предлагаю убедиться, что контейнер на самом деле крутится

Comment: Если я верно, понимаю, то контейнер "крутится". Доступ к базе внутри докера есть.

Comment: @Nik Может, я что-то не то заполняю в клиенте? Я была бы благодарна, если вы посмотрите скриншот по ссылке https://yadi.sk/i/z-cBXNGkouWhnw

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо разрешить в настройках БД подключения по паролю. Для этого надо найти файл `pg_hba.conf` и в нём добавить строку:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Вот документация, может быть будет полезно: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/auth-pg-hba-conf

Comment: Ничем не поможет, если нет сетевого подключения. А в вопросе проблема именно с сетью, на правила hba ругается именно фразой что запрещено правилами hba.